# Does it matter the order you tag your question

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I recently [posted a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889062/why-does-an-mvc-view-need-to-exist-in-the-view-directory-to-work) and someone edited my message, but all they did was reorder the tags I had already used.

(**Edit:** they did actually correct one, I just noticed)

Is there any benefits to the order in which you add tags? personally I thought there wasn't any weighting?

Comment: I just tested it on this question.  They definitely auto-order the tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They did not just rearrange your tags, they changed one of them slightly.

And, no, the order doesn't matter. (The site will auto-order the tags for you according to tag popularity.)

See the slight difference between [asp.net-mvc-3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3) and [asp.net-mvc-3-rc2](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3-rc2).

Comment: @jjnguy: just noticed that myself, but they did reorder, razor was my first tag.

Comment: @Luke, the order doesn't matter, and the reason the tags were reordered I'm sure was because the site auto sorts the tags by use.  So tags with more use go first on the post.

Comment: @jjinguy I don't know if you should encourage my OCD behaviour with gratefulness :)

Comment: Didn't know that, so they just put the most popular one on the `<title>`?

Comment: @Trufa, yeah.  They make sure the popular tag is in the title.  And they order tags by popularity.

Answer (score 6):

Tags are ordered by frequency from left to right.

On metas, the mod-only tag, if present, will always be on the far left followed by any required tags.

Comment: I just noticed [a revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/45714/revisions) that shows a changed order of tags: `[self-answer] [discussion]` into the order described above: `[discussion] [self-answer]`. So: am I right to assume that tags are ordered when saving? (Rather than when rendering?)

Comment: @arjan correct they are ordered at time of save