# How do I edit the order of tags on a question?

Tags: support, tags, edits

I have just tried to edit the tags on [How does the new Windows 8 Runtime (WinRT) compare to Silverlight and WPF?,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416826/how-does-the-new-windows-8-runtime-winrt-compare-to-silverlight-and-wpf/7426405#7426405) so that “WinRt” comes first.   When I saved my edit the tag order did not change.

(I wished to change the tag order, so that the generated page title is better for google)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77808/does-it-matter-the-order-you-tag-your-question - tags are ordered by popularity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible: The tags are automatically ordered from the most frequently used tag to the less used one.

Comment: Can we make it possible? See: http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/can-i-set-the-order-of-the-tags-in-a-question I am trying to improve the visibility of a new Tag.