# Does the order of tags matter?

Tags: discussion

I want to know if the order of tags matter when you ask a question?

I want my questions to first reach people who know [Groovy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29) in my case and then people who know [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29). But Stack Overflow orders Java first and then Groovy. Will that affect my relevancy?

Comment: The tags get reordered by how many questions they appear on, whatever order you put them in.

Comment: @Catija not mine is different , the one you told is about how to edit , i am asking if editing will matter or no ?Please read carefully before you claim such stuff'

Comment: The answer is the same... If I actually thought it was an exact dupe, I would have voted as such... hence the "possible duplicate" wording.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the order you add the tags doesn't matter because you don't actually get to set the order of the tags.

Tag order is determined by the popularity of that tag, not by the order you select it.

As noted by Shadow Wizard in the comments, this order is fixed based on the tag popularity *at the time of the last edit*. They do not update automatically. Editing the question can alter the order the tags appear **if** the popularity of the tag has changed in the interim.

See "[How do I edit the order of tags on a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109531/how-do-i-edit-the-order-of-tags-on-a-question)" for reference.

Comment: Worth to mention that the tags are re-ordered when editing. So when editing old questions, many times they will change order.

Comment: Interesting, so the tags are fixed in order when the question is created unless it's edited... so if the popularity of a tag changes, the order doesn't change unless you edit the question?

Comment: That is true. Take [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5290/add-the-ability-to-flag-an-edit-for-moderator-attention) for example. By now, [tag:flags] got more questions than [tag:moderation], so editing the question will result in tag order change. This makes sense, ordering the tags on the fly is expensive, and will take valuable time. Having it as static list means faster load time of the page, and it's not something worth of its own caching.